# How to write a simple mutter plugin?

Tags: window-manager, desktop-environment, gnome-shell, mutter

I want to create a very simple Desktop Environment using mutter or libmutter. 
I found out that mutter is a very simple wm but it can only be customized if I write a plugin for it. so I want to create a `gnome-shell` like plugin for mutter which would only tweak some window animation styles. but I am very new to creating such a thing so I would want to know how to get started.

I would want it to be as simple as possible and possible in a single script file (as I want to tweak very little)  .. also how do I compile it and make it to start like gnome-shell does.?